# Users with Edit Permissions can not see documents version 0.1 in Document Library?

Tags: 2010, document-library, permissions, sharepoint-server

I have copied a lot of documents into a folder in a document library.

- settings: versioning with x.x versions
- consequence: all those documents are currently version 0.1

For me it makes sense, that normal **visitors** or even **members** can not see those draft documents. But I would have expected that other users with **edit** permissions or even more can see them and edit them.

This is not the case. My colleague with **Contribute** permissions can not see them.

Is this normal? How can I create a group of users which can see such documents even in version 0.1?

Comment: On my site, only those in the "Members" and "Owners" groups could see the .x versions until they were published. Any other group, irregardless of the group permissions, could not see it. I don't know why this is, but it's the way it was working for me. I guess I'm saying, you're not alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the issue is related to files that have been uploaded to Sharepoint, but they have never been checked-in. Imagine the following scenario:

1. Someone uses the Explorer View to upload some files
2. The library requires users to check-in/out the documents (Require Check-in / Check-out), so the files are automatically checked-out to the user
3. The user does not know that he needs to check them in, so he never visits Sharepoint to do this.

In this case, there is no checked-in version and no users will be able to see these files, apart from those with Full Control permission level.

To see if this is the case, the files can be seen from Library Settings > Manage files which have no checked in version.

Comment: thanks. This is definitely the case. I uploaded the documents via Windows Explorer and wanted someone else to "process" them by adding metadata. This seems to be impossible without at least once checking them in...

Comment: For me it was not this but Waqas' answer that described the situation I was experiencing.

Answer (score 4):

It is normal, If your **draft item security** setting is set to `Only Users Who can apporve items(and the author of the item).`

To specify who can view drafts, you must have permission to design a list or library.

The following procedure applies only to libraries that track both major and minor versions and lists or libraries that require content approval.

1. If the list or library is not already open, click its name on the
   Quick Launch.

If the name of your list or library does not appear, click View All Site Content, and then click the name of your list or library.

On the Settings menu Settings menu, click List Settings, or click the settings for the type of library that you are opening.

For example, in a document library, click Document Library Settings.

1. Under General Settings, click Versioning settings.
2. In the Draft Item Security section, under Who should see draft items
   in this list or under Who should see draft items in this document
   library, click the group of users whom you want to enable to view
   drafts.

The option for users who can approve items is available only if your library requires content approval.

1. Click OK.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/specify-who-can-view-drafts-HA010098643.aspx

Comment: thanks! this option is already set. Did I understand correctly, that the users need "Design" permissions - contribute is not enough?

Comment: which option set, there are 3 items?

Comment: ah, sorry. At the moment we have set `Only users who can edit items` (the third one is not available) and I forgot to say that we do NOT require approval at the moment (that seemed to complicated for me)

Comment: in that case all the user with edit permission can view the draft version...if it is not wokring as per the expectation...i would change to read items options and save it and then go back and change to edit items